# find first occurence of a sum of digits in an endless number

Tags: php, math, search, numbers

For an endless number such as Pi, how would one go about finding the first occurrence of an exact sum of digits for a given number n.

For example. If n=20

Pi=3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939...

then the first occurrence is from digit 1 to digit 5 since:
1+4+1+5+9=20

if n=30, then the first occurrence is from digit 5 to digit 11 
since 9+2+6+5+3+5=30

answer should have a working php demo

Comment: I would setup a FIFO queue, limited to 20 entries. Loop through each number, and throw it into the queue; once you add #21, #1 will be dropped. Then sum it up each time you add a new item.

Comment: I think the `n` long FIFO is not a good solution. E.g. `n=20` and the sequence is `1000000000000000000000991222222` (it contains 21 zeros) then the correct sum would be `1+(27*0)+9+9+1`, from digit 0 to 24. and this is longer than 20. My solution would be an infinite long FIFO from which I pop if the sum of the elements is greater than the desired sum.

Comment: Should the integer part of the number (e.g. 3 for Pi) be considered as a valid digit/position?

Comment: @Jeto no.......

Comment: @user813801 OK........ But that was unclear (and the current answer assumed it was). Also, could you please share your attempts?

Comment: For 30, shouldn't the first occurrence be 5+9+2+6+5+3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1 (suggested by Ashwin Bhat)

This implementation uses two pivots. The sum of digits between `$pivot_a` and `$pivot_b` is computed. Depending on the value of the sum, we increment `$pivot_b` (if the sum is less) or `$pivot_a` (if the sum is greater). If the sum is equal to `$n`, break. The values of the pivots give the appropriate digit indices.

```php
$pi = "314159265358979323846264338327950288419716939";

$n = 30;

$pivot_a = $pivot_b = 0;
$sum = 0;

for( ; $pivot_b < strlen($pi); ) {

    if($sum < $n) {
        $sum += $pi[$pivot_b++];
    } elseif ($sum > $n) {
        $sum -= $pi[$pivot_a++];
    } else {
        print('Solution found from digit '.$pivot_a.' to '.$pivot_b.'.');
        exit;
    }
}

print('No match was found.');
```

### Method 2

This implementation uses one pivot only, from which it starts summing up the digits. If the sum happens to be greater than the desired value, it resets the sum to zero, shifts the pivot one position and starts the summing again.

```php
$pi = "314159265358979323846264338327950288419716939";

$n = 30;


// Let's sum up all the elements from $pivot until we get the exact sum or a 
// number greater than that. In the latter case, shift the $pivot one place.

$pivot = 0;
$sum = 0;

for($k=0 ; $sum != $n && $k < strlen($pi) ; $k++) {
    $sum += $pi[$k];

    print($pi[$k]);

    if($sum > $n) {
        print(' = '.$sum.'  fail, k='.($pivot+1).PHP_EOL);
        $sum = 0;
        $k = $pivot++;
    } elseif($sum < $n) {
        print("+");
    }
}

print(' = '.$n.' found from digit '.$pivot.' to '.$k.'.');
```

The implementation is not very effective but tries to explain the steps. It prints

```
3+1+4+1+5+9+2+6 = 31  fail, k=1
1+4+1+5+9+2+6+5 = 33  fail, k=2
4+1+5+9+2+6+5 = 32  fail, k=3
1+5+9+2+6+5+3 = 31  fail, k=4
5+9+2+6+5+3 = 30 found from digit 4 to 10.
```

Comment: method2 vastly faster. especially for large numbers. ex. 270119  took 0.01 seconds versus 104 seconds for method 1

Comment: how would one start from an offset of pi? ex. start from digit 10 instead of digit 0

Comment: My first idea is to remove the unwanted part from the string with [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php); i.e. `$pi = substr($pi, 10);` Whit this, the found indices are relative to the offset. To get absolute indices, add the value of the offset.
The second solution is to initialize `$pivot_a = $pivot_b = 10;` or `$pivot = $k = 10;`. This method gives absolute indices, (you can get relative indices by subtracting the value of the offset).

Comment: so for k of 2nd solution, instead of "for ($k=0.." change to "for ($k=10.."?

Comment: You have to change `$k=0` to `$k=10` **and** `$pivot = 0` to `$pivot = 10`.

Comment: Also, I've updated Method 1, now it should run faster (there are no nested loops in the updated implementation).

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this is using sliding window that will maintain the sum. so maintain two pointers say `i` and `j`. Keep increasing `j` and adding the elements inside. when it crosses the desired sum increase `i` and decrease the element at i. Then keep increasing `j` until the sum is reached or the sum overflows so you repeat the above process.

Example sum = 30

`1`41592653589793238 >> i=j=0 current_sum = 1

`1415926`53589793238 >> i=0 j=6 current_sum=28

in the next iteration adding 5 will result in current_sum>30 so hence you increment i

1`415926`53589793238 >> i=1 j=6 current_sum=27

14`15926`53589793238 >> i=2 j=6 current_sum=23

14`159265`3589793238 >> i=2 j=7 current_sum=28

Keep going in this manner and it will finally reach the window that is equal to the sum =30 . That should break you out of the loop and help you find the answer.

Comment: I am not familiar with php, will python, java do?  @user813801

Comment: looks like nasy made a php version of your answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach. It builds an array of sums along the way and, on every iteration, attempts to add the current digit to the previous sums, and so on, while always only keeping the sums that are still relevant (< target).

The function either returns:

- an array of 2 values representing the 0-based index interval within the digits,
- or `null` if it couldn't find the target sum

Code:

```
function findFirstSumOccurrenceIndexes(string $digits, int $targetSum): ?array
{
  $sums = [];

  for ($pos = 0, $length = strlen($digits); $pos < $length; $pos++) {
    $digit = (int)$digits[$pos];
    if ($digit === $targetSum) {
      return [$pos, $pos];
    }
    foreach ($sums as $startPos => $sum) {
      if ($sum + $digit === $targetSum) {
        return [$startPos, $pos];
      }
      if ($sum + $digit < $targetSum) {
        $sums[$startPos] += $digit;
      }
      else {
        unset($sums[$startPos]);
      }
    }
    $sums[] = $digit;
  }

  return null;
}
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/9t3vf**

Comment: thanks. but this answer is about 100x slower than the one by naszy